# Can't add custom Taxonomy to Custom Post Type

Tags: plugins

I am unable to add taxonomy to custom post types. But for same code if I add 'post' or 'page' it shows up fine. I can't pinpoint the problem.

Here is the code.

To register custom post type - working fine

*register_taxonomy($key, 'SH_job_listings', $value);*
if i replace 'SH_job_listings' with post or page it works fine but not for custom post type i created.

```
class SH_job_post_class{

    public function  __construct(){
        $this->register_job_Listings();
        $this->add_taxonomies();

    }

    public function register_job_Listings(){
        $args = array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Job Listings',
                'singular_name' => 'job Listing',
                'add_new' => 'Add New Job',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Job',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Jobs',
                'new_item' => 'New Item',
                'view_item' => 'View Item',
                'search_item' => 'Search Jobs',
                'not_found' => 'No Job Found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Job Found In Trash'
            ),
            'query_var' => 'job',
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'jobs/'
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            //'menu_icon' => admin_url().
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'thumbnail',
                'editor',
                'custom_fields'
            )
        );

        // This function is actually registering post type
        register_post_type('SH_job_listings', $args);
    }

    public function add_taxonomies(){
        $taxonomies = array();

        $taxonomies['job'] = array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'show_ui'  => true,
            'show_admin_column'=> true,
            'query_var' => 'job_type',
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'job/job_type'
            ),
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'job type',
                'singular_name' => 'Job Type',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Job Type',
                'update_item' => 'Update Job Type',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add  Job Type',
                'new_item_name' => 'New Job Type',
                'all_items' => 'All Job',
                'popular_items' => 'Popular Job Types',
                'search_items' => 'Search Job Types',
                'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Job Types with commas ',
                'add_or_remove_items' => 'Add or Remove Job Type',
                'choose_from_most_used' => 'Choose from most used Job Type'

            )
        );
        $this->register_all_taxonomy($taxonomies);

    }
    public function register_all_taxonomy($all_taxonomy){

        foreach($all_taxonomy as $key => $value){
            register_taxonomy($key, 'SH_job_listings', $value);
        }

    }

}

add_action('init', function(){
    new SH_job_post_class();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the parameter rules of both [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type):

> $post_type
>   (string) (required) Post type. (max. 20 characters, **can not contain capital letters** or spaces)

and [`register_taxonomy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy):

> $taxonomy
>   (string) (required) The name of the taxonomy. **Name should only contain lowercase letters** and the underscore character, and not be more than 32 characters long (database structure restriction)

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem. Got to read more carefully next time.